# How to access google app engine application using a python client

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using a python client to post requests(requests.post()) to google app engine application on local webserver (localhost:8080). This works and I finished testing my application.

My GAE application is NOT using OAuth.

When python client is used to post to deployed GAE application: https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/apiserver/v1/someapi - it fails (with 400:Bad request) since the url is https.

How to solve this ?

Comment: Have you looked in the error log ?

Comment: 400, Bad request: It was ProtoRpc was not finding the right type as parameters in request - since it was https.

Then I retrieved security certificate from myapp.appspot.com using openssl - which I am assuming is required(?). And then using it while making it a POST. 

Error Code: 403, Reason: sslRequired, Message: SSL is required to perform this operation. 

So I have not been able to use it the way I liked.

Comment: I gave up on http post and now trying to do it using remote_api way. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965990/how-to-access-remote-api-which-is-not-using-oauth?noredirect=1#comment51840601_31965990)